# How to pass callback function parameters to parent react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

Just wondering the best way to pass the letterSelected into the useLazyQuery fetchMovies query, so that I don't have to use the static variable of "A". I was hoping there was a way to pass it directly into fetchMovies. useLazyQuery is an apollo query.

```
const BrowseMovies = () => {

const [fetchMovies, { data, loading}] = useLazyQuery(BROWSE_MOVIES_BY_LETTER, {
    variables: {
        firstLetter: "A"
    }
})

return (
    <div className="browserWrapper">
        <h2>Browse Movies</h2>
        <AlphabetSelect 
            pushLetterToParent={fetchMovies}
        />
        {
            data && !loading &&
            data.browseMovies.map((movie: any) => {
                return (
                    <div className="browseRow">
                        <a className="movieTitle">
                            {movie.name}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
}

export default BrowseMovies
```

---

```
const AlphabetSelect = ({pushLetterToParent}: any) => {

const letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L', 'M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','#']

const [selectedLetter, setSelectedLetter] = useState("A")

const onLetterSelect = (letter: string) => {
    setSelectedLetter(letter.toUpperCase())
    pushLetterToParent(letter.toUpperCase())
}

return (
    <div className="alphabetSelect">
        {
            letters.map((letter: string) => {
                return(
                    <div 
                        className={selectedLetter === letter ? 'letterSelectActive' : 'letterSelect'} 
                        onClick={() => onLetterSelect(letter)}
                    >
                        {letter}
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
}
export default AlphabetSelect
```

Comment: Is `useLazyQuery` a custom hook, or imported and just used? I think we would need to see that code to help more.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery

It's an imported hook from the apollo react library :)

Comment: Your code seems already correct. You just had to write `pushLetterToParent({ variables : { firstLetter: letter.toUpperCase() } })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem solved by [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). `useLazyQuery` takes a gql query and options and returns a function to execute the query at a later time. Sounds like you want the child component to update the `variables` config parameter.

BrowseMovies

1. Move `firstLetter` state `BrowseMovies` component
2. Update query parameters/options/config from state
3. Add `useEffect` to trigger fetch when state updates
4. Pass `firstLetter` state and `setFirstLetter` state updater to child component

   ```
   const BrowseMovies = () => {
     const [firstLetter, setFirstLetter] = useState('');

     const [fetchMovies, { data, loading}] = useLazyQuery(
       BROWSE_MOVIES_BY_LETTER,
       { variables: { firstLetter } } // <-- pass firstLetter state
     );

     useEffect(() => {
       if (firstLetter) {
         fetchMovies(); // <-- invoke fetch on state update
       }
     }, [firstLetter]);

     return (
       <div className="browserWrapper">
         <h2>Browse Movies</h2>
         <AlphabetSelect 
           pushLetterToParent={setFirstLetter} // <-- pass state updater
           selectedLetter={firstLetter} // <-- pass state
         />
         {
           data && !loading &&
             data.browseMovies.map((movie: any, index: number) => {
               return (
                 <div key={index} className="browseRow">
                   <a className="movieTitle">
                     {movie.name}
                   </a>
                 </div>
               )
             })
         }
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```

AlphabetSelect

1. Attach `pushLetterToParent` callback to `div`'s `onClick` handler

   ```
    const AlphabetSelect = ({ pushLetterToParent, selectedLetter }: any) => {

      const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#';

      return (
        <div className="alphabetSelect">
          {
            letters.split('').map((letter: string) => {
              return(
                <div
                  key={letter}
                  className={selectedLetter === letter ? 'letterSelectActive' : 'letterSelect'} 
                  onClick={() => pushLetterToParent(letter.toUpperCase())}
                >
                  {letter}
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      )
    }
   ```